# Can I use gulp-imagemin with gulp-watch?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-imagemin

Can I use gulp-imagemin plugin with gulp-watch? So, I need to optimize images as soon as they are put into the folder.

Here is a part of my gulpfile.js:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.watch('dist/images/**', function(event) {
    gulp.run('images');
  });
});

// Image files

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in your watch task, you're watching image changes in **'dist/images/**'**..
you should change that to **'src/images/*'**

Also in your image task, you're watching only for images directly in the images folder (non recursive). I'd recomment to listen to **'src/images/**'**

Your new gulpfile will look like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/images/**', function(event) {
    gulp.run('images');
  });
});

// Image files

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/images/**')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

Hope that helps ;-)